# DI with CDI and 3rd party class: avoid constructor doing business logic called multiple times for each proxy construction

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, constructor, cdi, application-scope

I'm relativly new to EE / CDI for DI so maybe one of you could provide me with some tips for my problem:

I've got a 3rd party class which I would like to inject into other beans. In spring just needs some `<bean>` declaration and it's done. Using cdi it now takes a factory class:

```
public class XProducer {    
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public X createX(){
        return new X();
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly X`s constructor invokes rather expensive business logic and every time a proxy is created by cdi it's called but I can't change X's behaviour. This leaves me with the following options I don't really like:

- wrapping X in some ugly `Holder`-class,
- creating some facade and have to delgate methods to `X`

Are there any other options left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a case where you want to use `@javax.inject.Singleton` since its a third party, you won't need interceptor support, and singleton does not generate a proxy, so the constructor will only be called once.

Comment: Okay, using EJB then :) I initially rejected `@Singleton` due to  container managed concurrency creating a bottleneck having overlooked it can be disabled with `@ConcurrencyManagement(BEAN)`.

Comment: Why EJB? If you using `@javax.inject.Singleton` its from JSR-330, not EJB.